# ExecutorService Shutdown - Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, executorservice, kafka-consumer-api

I am fetching messages from Kafka and processing them using Executor service similar to below. I am not calling executorService.shutdown(). I have occasionally been seeing heapSize exception , but not sure if this could be one of the causes. How do the unused Runnable instances get removed after completion? Should I do anything specific to explicitly make it eligible for GC?

```
public class Consumer implements CommandLineRunner{

    ExecutorService executorService;
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50)
    executorService.submit(runnable);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation for `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`:

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating
>   off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most nThreads threads
>   will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted
>   when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a
>   thread is available. If any thread terminates due to a failure during
>   execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed
>   to execute subsequent tasks. The threads in the pool will exist until
>   it is explicitly shutdown.

For given example there will be at most 50 threads active in the thread pool and they are released when you call `shutdown` method.

If you do not keep references to your `Runnable`s they will be GCed when `Executor` is done with them. If you get out of memory exceptions this can be due to queued `Runnable`s in cases when executor can not keep up with the work submitted to him.

EDIT: Also out of memory exceptions can happen if your tasks take a lot of memory (obviously).